# Show existing X screen in X window on the other X screen

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg

I'm using linux machine with 3 monitors as separate X screens. One for desktop/control and 2 for full-screen video playback. Playback monitors can't be seen so I need the playback screens "previews" on the control screen (the video controls are already there). 
I'm using 2 VNC servers and 2 VNC viewers for that purpose but its very heavy and cpu-hungry solution even with downscaling. I wonder is there a lighter way to do that, maybe using some X server magic.

Comment: Why are you running 3 X servers instead of 1 with 3 monitors ?

Comment: 1. It's easier for me to set video destination and control screens with $DISPLAY rather than X coordinates.
2. I like that windows are screen bound.
3. Don't remember the details now but it was easier to config with 2 vid cards
4. Why not? 1 server for 3 screens won't solve my problem.

Comment: Well, the problem is now you need all these servers talking to each other to get previews. I'm thinking it might be a lot easier (and more efficient) to communicate within an X session than across one.

Comment: I'm ready to adopt 1 server config if there's a solution.

Comment: Here's an idea: Having all monitors on the same server opens up all kinds of [cool tricks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p3X7CdE2oc) you can do with compiz. There's the scale plugin which can show live previews of a group of windows for instance. The tricky part will be to find the right settings for your case since you can't see the other monitors...

Comment: Otherwise with your current setup, i guess you've explored all the options to make vnc [take up less resources](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-less-resource) ?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Looks like compiz might be that solution with 1 server setup. Can't test it on the machine now. I'm still doubt that 1 server can be used on 2 video cards with hardware acceleration, I'll check that. If your comment was the answer I'd have it marked as solution.

Comment: Edited the comments as answers for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single display + Compiz**

Here's an idea:  Having all monitors on the same display opens up all kinds of [tricks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p3X7CdE2oc) you can do with [compiz](http://www.compiz.org/). There's the scale plugin which can show live previews of a group of windows for instance. The tricky part will be to find the right settings for your case since you can't see the other monitors...

Answer (score 0):

**Tweak VNC**

Otherwise with your current setup, i guess you've explored all the options to make vnc [take up less resources](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-less-resource) ?